# Reading an Excel file in pandas Dataframe without index

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

```
import pandas
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@......../{db}"
                       .format(user="....",
                               pw=".....",
                               db="....."))
df=pandas.read_excel("trial.xlsx")
print(type(df))
df
df.to_sql('trail', con = engine, if_exists = 'append')
```

Did some editing in code. This is the full code. It throws this error:

> OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'") [SQL: INSERT INTO trail (`index`, name, class, `rank`) VALUES (%(index)s, %(name)s, %(class)s, %(rank)s)] [parameters: ({'index': 0, 'name': 'a', 'class': 'x', 'rank': 1}, {'index': 1, 'name': 'b', 'class': 'y', 'rank': 2}, {'index': 2, 'name': 'c', 'class': 'z', 'rank': 3}, {'index': 3, 'name': 'd', 'class': 'm', 'rank': 4})] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

As far as I can understand this error occurs because of that default indexing of pandas. Since my database table only has three columns and pandas dataframe had four columns including default indexing. So I want that indexing gone when pandas reads the Excel file.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: How many sheets inside the excel?

Comment: just one sheet in excel

Comment: pandas always generates an index for a dataframe. Which column in your excel should be the index? You are getting the error because as far as I can tell there is no keyword index available for the function pd.read_excel() See docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1):

Only add an `index=False` when sending the data to the database table as that table does not have have `index` column:

df.to_sql('trail', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', **index=False**)